# how to access methods inside a javascript class?

Tags: javascript

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    foo:function(){
        var = new Fung({
            go:function(this){
                this.bar();  
            }
        });
    },

    bar:function(){
        alert('hello world');
    }
});
```

Im trying to access method from inside nested class. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to show the definition of the `Class` constructor function.

Answer (score 3):

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    foo:function(){
        var that = this;
        var = new Fung({
            go:function(){
                that.bar();  
            }
        });
    },

    bar:function(){
        alert('hello world');
    }
});
```